# div tag class attribute contains lot of strings and cannot be replaced with css string definition string

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to develop an UI and the first step is to create CssLayout. Each CssLayout component is added hierarchically with and many CssLayout component.

The problem is when i run the application and inspect the div tags, the class attribute has extra strings that needs to be removed.

```
<div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget .content-container v- 
csslayout-.content-container v-has-width v-has-height" style="width: 100%; 
height: 100%;"><div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget .inner-content- 
container v-csslayout-.inner-content-container"></div></div>
```

and what I need is

```
<div class=".content-container">
      <div class=".inner-content-container">
      </div>
</div>
```

Java Code:

```
@StyleSheet("{css/spreadjsdefault.css}")
public class SpreadJSWidget extends CssLayout {

   /**
    * 
    */
   public SpreadJSWidget() {
      super();

      addStyleName(".content-container");

      CssLayout mainBox = new CssLayout();
      mainBox.addStyleName(".inner-content-container");

      addComponent(mainBox);

   }
```

spreadjsdefault.css (They are empty for now)

```
.content-container
{

}

.inner-content-container
{

}
```

Please advice !

Comment: I removed . in the java code and now, i can see the below <div class="content-container v-layout v-widget v-has-width v-has-height"><div class="inner-content-container v-layout v-widget">. However my target is to get only the names described.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. In order to be able to properly match the css rules, you have to omit the leading `.` when adding the style name, i.e. `addStyleName("contentContainer")`. This way, the css elements will match your style definition.
2. Css classes like `v-csslayout` are default classes defined by vaadin used by the default themes to provide a basic layout. They are there by default and can't (and actually shouldnt) be removed entirely. What you can do, however, is to define and overwrite these rules yourself. What's important: Either way, your custom classes will  still match when you define them in your style sheet and can overwrite the default theming.